Running Portalum.Zvt.EasyPay.exe with c#
I'm trying to run an .exe file (Portalum.Zvt.EasyPay.exe) with a parameter (--amount 1.23) in my C# program. Additionally, I would like to retrieve the error level (exit code).
The developer of the program provides some examples of how this is done in other languages:
Java:
var processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("Portalum.Zvt.EasyPay.exe", "--amount", "1.23");
var process = processBuilder.start();
var returnCode = process.waitFor();

Powershell
$process = Start-Process Portalum.Zvt.EasyPay.exe -WindowStyle Hidden -ArgumentList "--amount 1.23" -PassThru -Wait
$process.ExitCode

CMD
start /w Portalum.Zvt.EasyPay.exe --amount 1.23
echo %errorlevel%

I did find a way how to run the .exe file thru the cmd but it is not clean and im not getting the error level.
Process ps = new Process();
ps.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
ps.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
ps.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/k start /w /d ""C:\Users\jschw\Downloads\Portalum.Zvt.EasyPay\"" Portalum.Zvt.EasyPay.exe --amount 1.23";
ps.Start();
ps.StartInfo.Arguments = @"/k echo %errorlevel%";
ps.Start();
ps.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

Could someone please hlep me out?

It's an exe already so you don't need to use CMD.
ps.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\jschw\Downloads\Portalum.Zvt.EasyPay\Portalum.Zvt.EasyPay.exe";
ps.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
ps.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
ps.StartInfo.Arguments = "--amount 1.23";
ps.Start();
ps.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(ps.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());```


thanks you. I did try it out like that but the exe file did not run properly. After a lot of debugging i just found out that the exe could not find a config json file. I had to add the StartInfo.WorkingDirectory. Now it is working.
